# Does django field update nullable columns if you add a default value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have a field:

```
status = CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, I change this field to:

```
status = CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="GOOD")
```

does that mean that every object existing in the table with `status=None` will be converted to `status=GOOD`?

Does that mean I don't need to create an data migration file?

Comment: That is relatively easy to find out yourself. Also, you can always run `manage.py makemigrationts; manage.py migrate` and Django will not do anything if it doesn't need to.

Answer (score -1):

`null=True` means that object can be `null` in database.

`blank=True` means that value can be empty in your forms. empty doesn't mean `null` it means something like `""`(empty string).

when you don't provide value for a field in your form then it will use the default value.